# Wildcard Azure certificate for multiple sites

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service

I am looking to purchase a wildcard certificate from Azure for use on multiple azure subscriptions with one or more Azure Websites each.

Can Azure SSL certificates be used on multiple subscriptions or are they tied to the subscription they were purchased on?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, today that is possible since they have added the possibility to export the certificate as a PFX file.

See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f3e6faeb-5ed4-435a-adaa-987d5db43b80/faq-on-app-service-certificates-and-custom-domains?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Quote from that page (emphasis mine):

> Can I export my App Service certificate for use with other Azure services such as Cloud Services and so forth?
>
> We've gotten a lot of feedback from customers asking for this ability, so we now allow you to export your certificate as a PFX file so that you can use it **across multiple subscriptions** and Azure services. See this blog post for more information.

To export your certificate, see this SO answer: [export azure ssl certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836724/export-azure-ssl-certificate)