# Export Azure SSL certificate as pfx file

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service

I purchased a wild card certificate from azure. It sits right now in the Key Vault. I need to upload it to our other server which hosts one of our other applications for the same domain. There is no option to export the certificate as a .pfx file anywhere in azure portal.

Please help.

Comment: Is your other server in Azure? From what Scott Simms posted it sounds like you can reuse the cert ONLY within web apps in Azure. It's not for things outside of Azure and it can maybe be done for Azure IaaS VMs, but its not easy.

Comment: I'm also trying to export this key but seems like this is only possible with azure app service. had you able to make it?

Comment: You can export `.cert` using a certificate which you uploaded to azure web app, but you can not export `.pfx`. To see how to export `.cert`, take a look at this post: [Export SSL Certificate from Azure Web App](http://www.reza-aghaei.com/export-ssl-certificate-from-azure-web-app/)

Answer (score 10):

You can create a local PFX copy of Azure App Service Certificate using PowerShell.

Provide appropriate values from the following variables and save the script as `copyasc.ps1`.

Variables:

```
$appServiceCertificateName = "ascdemo"
$resourceGroupName = "ascdemorg"
$azureLoginEmailId = "user@microsoft.com"
$subscriptionId = "fb2c25dc-6bab-45c4-8cc9-cece7c42a95a"
```

copyasc.ps1:

```
$appServiceCertificateName = ""
$resourceGroupName = ""
$azureLoginEmailId = ""
$subscriptionId = ""

Login-AzureRmAccount
Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

$ascResource = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceName $appServiceCertificateName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType "Microsoft.CertificateRegistration/certificateOrders" -ApiVersion "2015-08-01"
$keyVaultId = ""
$keyVaultSecretName = ""

$certificateProperties=Get-Member -InputObject $ascResource.Properties.certificates[0] -MemberType NoteProperty
$certificateName = $certificateProperties[0].Name
$keyVaultId = $ascResource.Properties.certificates[0].$certificateName.KeyVaultId
$keyVaultSecretName = $ascResource.Properties.certificates[0].$certificateName.KeyVaultSecretName

$keyVaultIdParts = $keyVaultId.Split("/")
$keyVaultName = $keyVaultIdParts[$keyVaultIdParts.Length - 1]
$keyVaultResourceGroupName = $keyVaultIdParts[$keyVaultIdParts.Length - 5]
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -ResourceGroupName $keyVaultResourceGroupName -VaultName $keyVaultName -UserPrincipalName $azureLoginEmailId -PermissionsToSecrets get
$secret = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name $keyVaultSecretName
$pfxCertObject=New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 -ArgumentList @([Convert]::FromBase64String($secret.SecretValueText),"", [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable)
$pfxPassword = -join ((65..90) + (97..122) + (48..57) | Get-Random -Count 50 | % {[char]$_})
$currentDirectory = (Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath
[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = (Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath
[io.file]::WriteAllBytes(".\appservicecertificate.pfx", $pfxCertObject.Export([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pkcs12, $pfxPassword))
Write-Host "Created an App Service Certificate copy at: $currentDirectory\appservicecertificate.pfx"
Write-Warning "For security reasons, do not store the PFX password. Use it directly from the console as required."
Write-Host "PFX password: $pfxPassword"
```

Type the following commands in PowerShell console to execute the script:

```
Powershell –ExecutionPolicy Bypass
.\copyasc.ps1
```

You can find more details on Azure App Service Team Blog [Creating a local PFX copy of App Service Certificate](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2017/02/24/Creating-a-local-PFX-copy-of-App-Service-Certificate.html)

If you have an App Service Certificate that you would like to use outside of Azure App Service ecosystem, then give this a try and let us know how it goes. If you run into any issues, please let us know on the Stackoverflow or on the [Azure App Service forum.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)

Comment: C'mon guys, make this a one button export.

Comment: Steps I needed to run locally: 1. `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`, 2. `Install-Module AzureRM -AllowClobber` (not sure `-AllowClobber` is necessary though), 3. `Import-Module AzureRM`, 4. Run Dimitry's script. Hope this helps others. When done, consider changing back to your original execution policy for security concerns

Answer (score 2):

It is a one button export now.

go to your app service certificate resource

click export certificate

it will tell you go to key vault and provide a link to it

click that link

now click the cert

now click download

that download is a pfx file

Answer (score 1):

I've found [@dmitry-kazakov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3314998/dmitry-kazakov)'s answer to be helpful, but had to perform some minor updates to get it to work for me.

First I had to execute this command and assign it to `$azureUserPrincipalName`:

```
PS Azure:\> Get-Azureaduser

ObjectId                             DisplayName UserPrincipalName                                             UserType
--------                             ----------- -----------------                                             --------
89500455-0019-4059-8ef8-f1w32993z520 A User rmoore_roundlabinc.com#EXT#@rmooreroundlabinc.onmicrosoft.com Member
```

Then here is the updated script:

```
$appServiceCertificateName = "ascdemo" #This is the "Subject Name" in Azure, not "Name"
$resourceGroupName = "ascdemorg"
$azureLoginEmailId = "user@microsoft.com"
$subscriptionId = "fb2c25dc-6bab-45c4-8cc9-cece7c42a95a"
$azureUserPrincipalName = "user@microsoft.com#EXT#@user@microsoft.com.onmicrosoft.com"

Login-AzureRmAccount
Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

$ascResource= Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceName $appServiceCertificateName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType "Microsoft.CertificateRegistration/certificateOrders" -ApiVersion "2019-05-01"
$keyVaultId = ""
$keyVaultSecretName = ""

$certificateProperties=Get-Member -InputObject $ascResource.Properties.certificates[0] -MemberType NoteProperty
$certificateName = $certificateProperties[0].Name
$keyVaultId = $ascResource.Properties.certificates[0].$certificateName.KeyVaultId
$keyVaultSecretName = $ascResource.Properties.certificates[0].$certificateName.KeyVaultSecretName

$keyVaultIdParts = $keyVaultId.Split("/")
$keyVaultName = $keyVaultIdParts[$keyVaultIdParts.Length - 1]
$keyVaultResourceGroupName = $keyVaultIdParts[$keyVaultIdParts.Length - 5]
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -ResourceGroupName $keyVaultResourceGroupName -VaultName $keyVaultName -UserPrincipalName $azureUserPrincipalName -PermissionsToSecrets get
$secret = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name $keyVaultSecretName
$pfxCertObject=New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 -ArgumentList @([Convert]::FromBase64String($secret.SecretValueText),"", [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable)
$pfxPassword = -join ((65..90) + (97..122) + (48..57) | Get-Random -Count 50 | % {[char]$_})
$currentDirectory = (Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath
[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = (Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath
[io.file]::WriteAllBytes(".\appservicecertificate.pfx", $pfxCertObject.Export([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pkcs12, $pfxPassword))
Write-Host "Created an App Service Certificate copy at: $currentDirectory\appservicecertificate.pfx"
Write-Warning "For security reasons, do not store the PFX password. Use it directly from the console as required."
Write-Host "PFX password: $pfxPassword"

Powershell –ExecutionPolicy Bypass
.\copyasc.ps1
```

Answer (score 0):

Some docs are outdated, so here is a version of how to export it with PowerShell and Azure CLI on Mac + convert to PEM format for Nginx. Sharing just because it was painful for me, so hopefully it will be useful to someone:

```
pwsh
az keyvault secret show --vault-name KeyVaultName --name SecretName | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | pbcopy
echo $(pbpaste) > /tmp/pass
$secret=$(cat /tmp/pass)
$pfxCertObject= New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 -ArgumentList @([Convert]::FromBase64String($secret),"",[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable)
$pfxPassword = -join ((65..90) + (97..122) + (48..57) | Get-Random -Count 50 | % {[char]$_})
$currentDirectory = (Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath
[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = (Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath
[io.file]::WriteAllBytes("./appservicecertificate.pfx",$pfxCertObject.Export([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pkcs12,$pfxPassword))
openssl pkcs12 -in appservicecertificate.pfx -out /tmp/certificate.pem -clcerts -nokeys -password pass:$(echo $pfxPassword)
openssl pkcs12 -in appservicecertificate.pfx -out /tmp/certificate.key_protected -nocerts -password pass:$(echo $pfxPassword)
openssl rsa -in /tmp/certificate.key_protected -out /tmp/certificate.key -passin pass:$(echo $pfxPassword)
```

The last three lines are taken from [here](https://www.xolphin.com/support/Certificate_conversions/Convert_pfx_file_to_pem_file) and the middle part is a stripped-down version from the main [guide](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2017/02/24/Creating-a-local-PFX-copy-of-App-Service-Certificate.html)