# App service certificate - possibility of purchasing wildcard certificate with same domain name in different subscription

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, ssl-certificate

Is it possible to buy wildcard app service certificate with the same name (*.domain1.com) under multiple different subscriptions?

Would that cause any issues? may be invalidate existing certificates in other subscription?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question [Mohamed Shehata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10154293/mohamed-shehata)

> Is it possible to buy wildcard app service certificate with the same name (*.domain1.com) under multiple different subscriptions

As per the below screenshot conversation we can have wildcard app service with the same domain or we can even have same app service in different subdomains as well. And there won't be any issues regards with invalidating the existing certificate.

[image]

For Further information check [WildCard SSL certificate](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/93e4be31-475b-4e6f-861e-4ebe5e57aeae/wild-card-ssl-for-multiple-client-cloud-service?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42852941).

Comment: Thank you @SaiSakethGuduru for your reply. I'm already exporting and importing the same certificate to use across different subscription. I wanted to confirm If I can purchase an app service certificate with same domain name multiple times under different subscription. For example: 

- Subscription A: wild card app service certificate - *.companyxyz.com
- Subscription B: wild card app service certificate - *.companyxyz.com
- Subscription C: wild card app service certificate - *.companyxyz.com
- Subscription D: wild card app service certificate - *.companyxyz.com